# read.table in a loop to produce separated dfs

Tags: r, loops, syntax

I would like to produce `x` dataframes objects with different names (in the example: `df1`and `df2`, which will be based in the loop number.

This is what I tried...

```
x <- 2
for (k in 1:x){
  df[[k]] <- read.table(file=paste(k,"calls.txt", sep=""))
}
```

I got this error

> Object closure is not subsettable

I know that it is a simple syntax problem, but I did not find a solution here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write it like this

```
x <- 2
for (k in 1:x){
  df[k] <- read.table(file=paste(k,"calls.txt", sep=""))
}
```

You have to write `df[k]` instead of `df[[k]]`